# why my python code sometimes write out sensor readings twice at each crontab tilmestep

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

I wrote an simple python code to write sensor readings to a csv file. I set up to execute the code every 30 mins in crontab.

The code "sometimes" write out readings twice. Anything wrong in my code? Please help me.

Here is the output in a cvs file:

```
2015-04-29 06:00:10,-0.06418023
2015-04-29 06:00:11,-0.06418023
2015-04-29 06:05:10,-0.06419048
2015-04-29 06:05:10,-0.06419048
2015-04-29 06:10:11,-0.06423425
2015-04-29 06:15:10,-0.06420538
2015-04-29 06:20:10,-0.06421749
2015-04-29 06:20:10,-0.06421749
2015-04-29 06:25:11,-0.06422214
2015-04-29 06:30:10,-0.06426219
2015-04-29 06:30:11,-0.06422587
```

Here is the code:

```
outfile = open("Chamber1.csv", "a")
def BridgeData(e):
    global outfile
    CH1_1 = ch1.getValue(0)
    sleep(2)

    outfile.write(str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + "," + str(CH1_LC1) + "\n")
    sleep(2) 
sys.exit()
```

Here is the crontab under the root directory

```
*/5 * * * * /root/get_sensor_output.py
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your code. It could be that your function is called multiple times per second. Did you try to output the milliseconds (%f)? But with twice sleep(2) there should be a minimum of 4 seconds between the entries...

Comment: Why not make a while loop. sleep it for 30 min. after each write. and instead of using cron. make the script as a service! Or simplere. add it to rc.local like: get_sensor_output.py &. Then it will start on boot, run in the background and write to file every 30 min.

Comment: @MortenLarsen because using sleep will make it drift, whereas crontab keeps it in at even intervals always. Also Kuo-Hsien Chang is this your whole script? I can't see the call to BridgeData(e)...

Comment: you could use a "if time.time() > next_tm: ... next_tm += 300.0" type of system

Comment: The "drifting" couldbe accomodated also in the code! But it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe showing the real program might help to find the problem. What you've shown doesn't do anything useful, it just opens the file, defines a function and then runs into a `NameError` because `sys` isn't defined anywhere. Even if you just left out `import` statements, the opened file isn't closed properly, so you rely on the operating system to clean up after you. The ”function” looks dodgy — the argument isn't used, the `global` is unnecessary `ch1` and `outfile` are not given as arguments but have to exist on module level.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to close the outfile after the write.